# How Find Boundary of Loaded Map Tiles on Route Me Open Source Map?

Tags: cocoa-touch, gps, cllocationmanager, route-me

Using following open source Route Me app I am loading Maptiles

```
mapview = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
[mapview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
mapview.delegate = self;

id <RMTileSource> tileSource = [[[RMDBMapSource alloc] initWithPath:"@tilefile.db"] autorelease];

RMMapContents *rmcontents = [[RMMapContents alloc] initWithView:mapview tilesource:tileSource]; 
[self.view addSubview:mapview];//attached to mapview
```

It would be great if there is a method in RMMapContents that lets me get maps 4 corners as CLLocationCoordinate2D? There is a

```
- (RMSphericalTrapezium) latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox;
```

How do I get the 4 corner location from above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write yourself such a method:

```
RMSphericalTrapezium trap;
CLLocationCoordinate2D nePoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
    trap.northeast.latitude,
    trap.northeast.longitude);
```

The remaining 3 points, use southeast, southwest and northwest, analog to above.